# I have a code like this need to use my java script window location value in href

Tags: javascript, html

```
        <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li><a href="">Cycle Store & Services</a></li>
     </ul>

        function Demo(anchor) {
            var value = anchor.getAttribute('value')
            var locName=document.getElementById("locName").value;
            if(value.includes('&')){
                value = value.replace("&", "%26");
            }
           if(locName==""){
               alert("Please Select your Location");
           }
            else
                {
                     window.location = "http://www.citycontact.in/SpecificCategory.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
                }
        }
```

I have code like this i need to use "http://www.citycontact.in/SpecificCategory.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName; value in href

Comment: You are missing script tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. Script tag mission & variable value missing the ";" semicolan

```
 <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li><a href="">Cycle Store & Services</a></li>
     </ul>
<script>
function Demo(anchor) {
            var value = anchor.getAttribute('value');
            var locName=document.getElementById("locName").value;
            if(value.includes('&')){
                value = value.replace("&", "%26");
            }
           if(locName==""){
               alert("Please Select your Location");
           }
            else
                {
                     window.location = "http://www.citycontact.in/SpecificCategory.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
                }
 }

  </script>
```

Comment: need to implement complete window location value in href =""is it possible

Comment: @Abhi You mean inside a tag?

Comment: exactly is it possible to do like that

Comment: I think inside href not possible. Just try a tag onclick function.